how to use Stripe in flutter application?
I have stucked for using Stripe in my flutter app , and searched several youtube toturials , and alot of docs , still didnt fine a good solution how to implement that , i want to have an screen which gets :
Cards name , cards number , cvv , expire date
and i want to save them with a custom api ,  and if the user added the them and payment was done , for the next time the information be already there to use ,
but my main problem is how to config the Stripe payment
i created my own StripeKey , I'm using   flutter_stripe: ^9.4.0
can you please refrence any document or videos to get that done? thanks

I recommend reading the official documentation for flutter_stripe. For example this page explains how to use the PaymentSheet.
To save the card for later use, make sure you set setup_future_usage when creating the PaymentIntent in step 2.
